# Etching/engraving words onto wooden surface?

Tags: paint, wood, wood-carving, calligraphy, engraving

Am looking to create a personalised product which involves etching/engraving words into a pinewood surface that has been spray painted black. Any ideas on how to go about this and what is easiest and cheapest method? I have attached the surface below. [image]

Comment: What sort of scale are we talking about? I mean both the size of the letters and the total size of the text area

Comment: What have you looked at/tried? What equipment do you have available to you? What sort of finished result are you interested in? Please add some details, right now this is far too open-ended for a good answer.